# Root mean square term contribution

Tags: probability-theory

how can I find out each term contribution (%) in a RMS relation?
As an example:

```
a = 1.5
b = 0.5
RMS = sqrt(a^2 + b^2)
```

Cleary term "a" has a bigger contribution to the final RMS, but how much?
If I do simply

```
a/RMS = 0.948
b/RMS = 0.316
```

They don't add up to 100%

Comment: "Each term's percentage contribution" to a quantity is not well defined if the quantity is not the sum of those terms.

Comment: Thanks, Is there another way to quantify each term impact on the RMS value?

Comment: There are thousands of ways to do so. Whether they'll be useful is the question. What do you want to do with those quantified impacts?

Comment: Just to see the impact of each term, nothing more

Comment: I wonder how you got $0.77$ and $0.44$? By your formula, $RMS = \sqrt{1.5^2+0.5^2} \approx 1.5811$, and then $a/RMS \approx 0.95$.

Comment: In the case of arithmetic mean of $a$ and $b$, $AM = 1$, then $a/AM = 1.5$ and $b/AM = 0.5$. They also don't add up to $100\%$.

Comment: Copied and pasted from the wrong jupyter notebook ... I' correct

Comment: Could you provide some context? Why are you caring about RMS? What are a and b? Why are you actually interested in quantifying the percent contribution?

Comment: Sure, I calculated the predicted FWHM RMS in a telescope image like this: FWHM = sqrt(atmosphereFWHM^2 + guidingFWHM^2+scopeFWHM^2). And I wanted to know what term contributes more to the final image FWHM

Comment: Since you are "adding" by taking the square root of sum of squares (which you called RMS), do note that the ratios would "add" to $100\%$ by the same "addition":

$$S = \sqrt{a^2+b^2+\cdots}\\
\sqrt{\left(\frac aS\right)^2+\left(\frac bS\right)^2 +\cdots} = 1\\
\sqrt{\left(\frac{1.5}{\sqrt{5/2}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{0.5}{\sqrt{5/2}}\right)^2}=1$$

Comment: Thanks peter, this works nicely!